# SSIS Script Task - Failing to fill DataTable

Tags: ssis, datatable, oledb

I created a package to import files from an FTP server and need to process only new files, i.e. exclude files that have already been loaded (which is kept in a table).

I first run an Execute SQL Task to populate the "AlreadyLoadedFiles" object variable.  Then, I try to determine which files I need to process within a Script Task.  I first load the names of the files on FTP server, then remove those that have already been loaded.

I have no problem retrieving the names of the files that are on FTP, but the problem is that when I fill the OleDBDataAdapter with the object variable "AlreadyLoadedFiles", the resulting datatable is empty and I'm not sure why.

```
' Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
' Write scripts using Microsoft Visual Basic
' The ScriptMain class is the entry point of the Script Task.

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

<System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum

    Public Sub Main()
        '

        Dim vs As Variables
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()


        'We need to go to or FTP server
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForRead("FTPSourceDirectory", vs)

        Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("FTPServer")
        Dim ftp As FtpClientConnection = New FtpClientConnection(cm.AcquireConnection(Nothing))
        ftp.Connect()
        ftp.SetWorkingDirectory(vs("FTPSourceDirectory").Value.ToString())
        vs.Unlock()

        'We now need to get ourselves the files we have already seen
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForRead("AlreadyLoadedFiles", vs)


        da.Fill(dt, vs("AlreadyLoadedFiles").Value)
        MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count)
        vs.Unlock()


        Dim foldernames() As String
        Dim filenames() As String

        'Get the list of files that are there on the FTP server
        ftp.GetListing(foldernames, filenames)

        Dim dr As DataRow

        Dim ss As StringCollection = New StringCollection()

        Dim iFileCount As Integer

        If filenames Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Files Found")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'Need to loop through all the files found
            For iFileCount = 0 To filenames.GetUpperBound(0)

                'First we add all of the found files to the Array (Object) but only if they are CSV files

                Dim re As New Regex("^co_users_report_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$")

                If re.IsMatch(filenames(iFileCount).ToString()) Then
                    ss.Add(filenames(iFileCount).ToString())
                    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", filenames(iFileCount).ToString(), "", 0, True)
                End If
                For Each dr In dt.Rows
                    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", dr(0).ToString(), "", 0, True)
                    If dr(0).ToString() = filenames(iFileCount).ToString() Then
                        MessageBox.Show(dr(0).ToString)
                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", "Removed " & filenames(iFileCount).ToString() & " from array because it was previously loaded.", "", 0, True)

                        ss.Remove(filenames(iFileCount).ToString())
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If

        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("FilesForFTPDownload", vs)

        vs(0).Value = ss


        vs.Unlock()

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm using SQL Server (SSIS) 2008 R2 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you break this into multiple components.  Have a Script Task, like the one you have above, pull the necessary data from the ftp site and save it as a flat file.  Then build use a data flow task to read the flat file and process accordingly.  While the way you are doing it is valid, I don't believe it is as efficient as it could be if you used additional SSIS components.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue - it was the auditing framework that was resetting ADO Rowset...